# Date Format Error java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type

Tags: java, jdbc, jsf-2, primefaces

I am displaying date in JSF using `pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy"`.

When I am trying to insert/update date values into my oracle DB, I am getting

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
```

because my date format before insert or update is in this format

```
Wed Feb 09 00:00:00 AST 2011
```

How can I correctly insert or update my date values to Oracle Db and what is the best approach for doing this?

*Update 1*

My db insert code.

```
private void editSchedule(Schedule schedule)
        Object[] values = { schedule.getStartDate(),
                schedule.getVacationId() };             
        Connection connection = null;       
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null; 
        try {                           
            connection = datacon.getConnection();               
            preparedStatement = prepareStatement(connection, SQL_EDIT, values);         
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();          

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("errro "+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // TODO: handle exception
            close(connection, preparedStatement);
        }

    }
```

PreparedStaement code part

```
public static PreparedStatement prepareStatement
        (Connection connection, String sql, Object... values)
            throws SQLException
    {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql
            );
        setValues(preparedStatement, values);
        return preparedStatement;
    }

    public static void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Object... values)
        throws SQLException
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            preparedStatement.setObject(i + 1, values[i]);
            logger.info("sql  "+Arrays.asList(values));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to include the data as *text* when you're inserting/updating. Don't do that - use a `java.sql.Date` in a `PreparedStatement`. Introducing unnecessary string conversions is a really bad idea - it makes your code very brittle, and makes the code more confusijng: keep your data in an appropriate data type as long as you possibly can.

Comment: I am not trying to include or convert data as text. In my code startDate is declared as Date not as String. But still when I try to insert to DB, the format is different that of `DD-MMM-YYYY`. I am not sure how come my date format changed to `Wed Feb 09 00:00:00 AST 2011` In my bean I have `for (Schedule editValues : beanValues) { editValues.setStartDate(selectedRow.getStartDate());` For DB update code I have error coming from this line `preparedStatement = prepareStatement(connection, SQL_EDIT, values);` where values is declared as `Object[] values`

Comment: @Polappan: What do you mean by "the format is different"? In the database it should just be a DATETIME. It doesn't logically *have* a format. It sounds like your SQL may be incorrect... please post more of your code.

Comment: @Polappan: Any reason for always using `setObject` instead of explicitly setting the parameter using `setDate`? I'd at least *try* that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I have a question setObject is parent of setDate correct?

Comment: @Polappan: What do you mean by "parent"? And what *exact* type is `schedule.getStartDate()`? For example, if it's a java.util.Date, you might want to create a java.sql.Date instead.

Comment: I mean `setObject` might take all objects regardless of date or String! `schedule.getStartDate()` is of `java.util.Date`

Comment: @Polappan: Yes, it does - and I would *expect* it to work, but at least for the sake of experimentation I'd try using `setDate`. As I say, you might want to try creating a `java.sql.Date` value too, wrapping the `java.util.Date`.

Comment: @Polappan: I was only suggesting using `java.sql.Date` for the SQL part - you can use `java.util.Date` for the rest, but create a copy as a `java.sql.Date` when you do the insert.

Comment: Finally I managed to resolve this by the following way. I kept startDate type as java.util.Date and before insert/update I did a conversion from `util.Date` to `sql.Date` by `java.sql.Date sqlStartDate = new java.sql.Date(schedule.getStartDate().getTime());` This way I could get date in sql.Date and I could pass as setObject in preparedStatement method. Thanks a lot for your time and answers. Appreciated.

Comment: @Polappan: Yup, that's what I was proposing :)

Comment: Thanks. I found a strange behavior, when I change to java.sql.Date my method in managedBean doesn't work. I have created a different thread for this  though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547459/bean-method-not-getting-invoked-when-changed-to-java-sql-date. Anyways thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 7):

JDBC only understands `java.sql.Date`, `java.sql.Time` and `java.sql.Timestamp` as SQL column types, not `java.util.Date`.

You need to change

```
    Object[] values = { schedule.getStartDate(),
            schedule.getVacationId() };
```

by

```
    Object[] values = { new java.sql.Date(schedule.getStartDate().getTime()),
            schedule.getVacationId() };
```

Then it'll work. Just keep using `java.util.Date` in your model. JSF in turn doesn't understand `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: Thanks BalusC for the answer, little though because I was struggling for this for the past some time. :-)

Comment: And if you have a javaq.util.Date, you can simply convert it using: new java.sql.Date(myJavaUtilDate.getTime())

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String dateToSQLFormat(Date date){
        Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String ret=formatter.format(date);
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Why introduce an unnecessary string conversion at all? There are much better ways of passing strongly-typed data in JDBC.