# Bean method not getting invoked when changed to java.sql.Date

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a strange issue with one of my bean method.
If I make date datatype from `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Dat`e, one of the method in
my managedBean called `actionEdit` is not getting invoked when I click a button in jsf page.

My actionEdit() method

```
public void actionEdit(){           
        try {

            beanValues.add(selectedRow);
            for (Schedule editValues : beanValues) {
                editValues.setStartDate(selectedRow.getStartDate());
                editValues.setRemarks(selectedRow.getRemarks());

            }
            ScheduleDAO.editSchedule(beanValues);
            beanValues.clear();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            logger.info("exception  " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and it is called in jsf like the following

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" 
                        action="#{schedule.actionEdit()}">                                                  
                        </p:commandButton>
```

What could be the reason for this behavior? Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it back to `java.util.Date` and use `java.sql.Date` in the persistence layer **only**.

See also my answer on your previous question: [Date Format Error java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545331/date-format-error-java-sql-sqlexception-invalid-column-type/9548205#9548205).

Comment: Thanks I will take a look. But why method stopped working when I change to java.sql.Date? Doesn't get invoked at all!

Comment: A conversion failure had occurred. Read the server logs or add `<h:messages>` to see missing error messages. JSF can't convert a string submitted value to `java.sql.Date`, only to `java.util.Date`. The `java.sql.Date` should be used in JDBC context **only**, not in the model.

Comment: Nice explanation to make me understand. Appreciated.